# Why does {pf32} return the wrong value on Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

When using **Inno Setup** as my installer I need to access the [{pf32}](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) constant. However, even when running **Inno Setup** on a 64-bit architecture computer the return value of `{pf32}` is still:

> `c:\Program Files\` rather than `c:\Program Files (x86)\`.

Why is this? On a 64-bit architecture computer `{pf32}` should return `c:\Program Files (x86)`!

Is this a bug in Inno Setup?

Here is the log:

```
<U+FEFF>2018-03-21 11:04:23.399   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+01:00)
2018-03-21 11:04:23.399   Setup version: Inno Setup version 5.5.9 (u)
2018-03-21 11:04:23.399   Original Setup EXE: C:\Users\foo\installer-win.exe
2018-03-21 11:04:23.399   Setup command line: /SL5="$704EE,50905217,214528,C:\Users\foo\installer-win.exe" /log=c:\users\foo\install.log
2018-03-21 11:04:23.399   Windows version: 10.0.16299  (NT platform: Yes)
2018-03-21 11:04:23.399   64-bit Windows: Yes
2018-03-21 11:04:23.399   Processor architecture: x64
2018-03-21 11:04:23.399   User privileges: Administrative
2018-03-21 11:04:23.415   64-bit install mode: No
2018-03-21 11:04:24.649   Created temporary directory: C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\is-UR59N.tmp
2018-03-21 11:04:29.930   Starting the installation process.
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Directory for uninstall files: C:\Program Files\prog1
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Creating new uninstall log: C:\Program Files\prog1\unins000.dat
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   -- File entry --
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\prog1\unins000.exe
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Time stamp of our file: 2018-03-21 11:04:23.118
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Installing the file.
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Uninstaller requires administrator: Yes
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Successfully installed the file.
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   -- File entry --
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\prog1\packet_filter.dll
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Time stamp of our file: 2018-03-21 02:53:36.000
2018-03-21 11:04:30.087   Installing the file.
2018-03-21 11:04:30.102   Successfully installed the file.
2018-03-21 11:04:30.102   -- File entry --
2018-03-21 11:04:30.102   Dest filename: C:\Program Files\prog1\prog1.exe
```

And here is how `DefaultDirName` is defined in my `template.iss`:

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={pf32}\prog1
```

Note that when I specifically add:

```
[Setup]
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

Then and only then does `{pf32}` appear to properly expand to `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Comment: How are you seeing the value?  What's your script look like?  What does the run log show?

Comment: @mirtheil i'm just using it in `[Setup]` where i'm setting `DefaultDirName={pf32}\foo`  . I notice that if i set `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64` inside `[Setup]` too, then `{pf32}` DOES return the correct folder -- but i shouldn't have to set this, should i? and is there any downside to setting it?

Comment: Post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.  Run your example.  Post the log from the run.

Comment: For me `{pf32}` returns `C:\Program Files (x86)`, as expected. As mirtheil commented, we need [mcve] and a full log file.

Comment: Run the installer from the **command line** using the `/log` parameter and supply the log results in your question. The issue you have raised is rather fundamental so something has to be going on somewhere.

Comment: thanks guys @AndrewTruckle and co - i ran the installer with `/log` and you can see that it detects the system as 64 bit but the installer does not run in 64 bit mode....and the result of `{pf32}` is clearly just `C:\Program Files\`

Comment: Is it a fresh install? Could it be reusing existing folder? Try uninstall first.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle hmm, that's a pain cos it's a bunch of proprietary code that ill have to spend significant time to clean up to post publicly :( Out of itnerest, why do you need to see it though? surely all that matters is `DefaultDirName`  since that's where it installs to? and it's based on `{pf32}`

Comment: @AndrewTruckle oh it's not a fresh install! Can innosetup detect this? and re-use a folder? how does it know? wow

Comment: I removed comment about seeing script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DefaultDirName` Help states:

[image: Help]

It states:

> If `UsePreviousAppDir` is `yes` (the default) and Setup finds a previous version of the same application is already installed, it will substitute the default directory name with the **directory selected previously**.

I think if you uninstall the program and try again with the log. It is defaulting to last installed folder.

`UsePreviousAppDir` Help:

[image: Help]

Comment: Thanks I'll try this soon as I get home!